# Optional NSArray - Anyobject has no subscript members

Tags: swift, nsarray, nsdictionary, option-type, snapshot

I am trying print out the first object in an Optional NSArray I am returning from an online database. Nothing is printed out. Not sure how to unwrap an optional NSArray into an an array which I can index. Right now only trying to print out the first value in the NSArray.

```
fireBaseRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

                if !snapshot.exists() { return }

                for item in snapshot.children {
                print("This is the child value of reference", item.value["reference"])

                    if let referenceObjects = item.value["reference"] {
                        print("This is the first value", referenceObjects[0]) //error is Anyobject? has no subscript members
                    }

                }

            })
```

I receive the following

```
This is the child value of track-titles Optional(<__NSArrayM0x618000049000>(
The Chainsmokers - Don't Let Me Down (Illenium Remix),
Flume - Say It ft. Tove Lo (Illenium Remix),
The Chainsmokers Ft. Halsey - Closer (GhostDragon Remix),
Major Lazer & Showtek - Believer,
Fire,
ONE DANCE -- DRAKE (feat. Wizkid & Kyla),
Let Me Love You - Justin Bieber (Trap Edit)
)
)
```

Comment: Please add the output that you're currently getting.

Comment: what *is* `item.value["reference"]`? You talk about NSArray but try to unwrap it as NSDictionary.

Comment: @luk2302, it is the title of the tree or reference name I am getting the NSArray from.. I am using firebase.. yea don't know what I'm doing there with the NSDictionary...

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, referenceObjects is an NSDictionary, not an NSArray. Therefore when you ask for referenceObjects[0] the runtime will try and retrieve a value for the key 0.

If you want to retrieve an NSArray, then something like the following should work:

```
if let referenceObjects = item.value["reference"] as? NSArray where !referenceObjects.isEmpty {
    print("This is the first object: \(referenceObjects.first!)")
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @cnichs27 Regardless, you still need to cast.

Answer (score -1):

The snapshot was coming back as an optional NSArray so you have to use the conditional form of downcasting in case this object is nil.

```
if let referenceObjects = item.value["reference"] as? NSArray {
 print(referenceObjects[0])
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may answer the question, it doesn't provide any context to explain how or why. Consider adding a sentence or two to explain your answer.

Comment: Did my answer not answer your question? Feedback welcome as i am confused.

Comment: Also, the answer you presented will fail if referenceObjects happens to be empty.

Comment: @Sparky yes it did not work, i got an compiler error that stated NSArray has no member `isEmpty`